# Calling a JavaScript Geocoding function from within an MVC4 Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to call a Microsoft example JavaScript function called StartGeocoding from within one of my MVC4 controllers.  The controller's action that I want to use is my AddNew ActionResult method that creates a new record in the sql server database.  Before the                 db.Jobs.Add(job); and db.SaveChanges(); calls in the ActionResult method I would like to call StartGeocoding(Address) and pass to it a string I create (Address) with the model's Address, City, State and Zip fields concatenated together.  Then when the JS function returns the latitude and longitude I can just update the model with those values so they are saved when the record is created.

What is the syntax for calling a JS function from within an MVC controller so that I can pass it the address and get back the longitude and latitude values from the JS script?  Where should I save the JS scripts that are going to be called from the controller?  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: JavaScript is a ClientSide Language. Do not call it - nor try to call it - from within a controller.

Comment: gotcha, ok, so the script and call should be moved to the View?  maybe on the blur event of the zip code text box make a call to the StartGeocoding function?

Comment: For example - or on form submit. But keep in mind, that userdata is never ever trustworthy. So if you need reliable geocodes, read the js and build it with c# in your server logic.